# "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" when signing Android app

Tags: android, jar-signing

When I compile my Android app in release mode and try to sign it, I get the following error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

I set `key.store` in `ant.properties` to a relative path to my keystore file. There are no spaces in the file name or path. I'm certain that I'm using the correct password for the keystore because I can use the `keytool -list` command to view it. What else could be causing this error?

**Update:**

When I use an absolute path I get the following error message:

> Value for 'keystore' is not valid. It must resolve to a single path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the problem turns out to be very trivial and difficult to catch. I had quotes around the value of the `key.store` property in my `ant.properties` file. Apparently something in the build chain includes the quotes as part of the property's value. After removing the quotes, I compiled and signed my app just fine.